# How to add Unicode emoji to the Internet Archive?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, web-crawler, archive, emoji

When visiting a website that contains Unicode emoji through the Wayback Machine, the emoji appear to be broken, for example:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210524131521/https://tmh.conlangs.de/emoji-language/

The emoji "" is rendered as "ðŸ˜€" and so forth:

[image: Picture showing emoji incorrectly rendered as various special and accented characters]

This effect happens if a page is mistakenly rendered as if it was ISO-8859-1 encoded, even though it is actually UTF-8.

So it seems that the Wayback Machine is somehow confused about the character encoding of the page.

The original page source has a HTML5 `<!doctype html>` declaration and is valid HTML according to [W3C's validator](https://validator.w3.org/). The encoding is specified as `utf-8` using a `meta charset` tag.

The original page renders correctly on all major platforms and browsers, for example Chrome on Linux, Safari on Mac OS, and Edge on Windows.

Does the Internet Archive crawler require a special way of specifying the encoding, or are emoji through UTF-8 simply not supported yet?

Comment: Why not asking directly to them? About encoding: browsers have a different algorithm (never trust to much meta charset). Specify maybe also in html, and check if you have some special characters at beginning. W3C has also a recommended algorithm to detect encoding, but... it is complex, so archive may got some bugs there. Contact them and ask.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything obvious. I sent an e-mail to them now. Will post an update here if I receive a reply. :-)

Comment: Run validator verbosely for [page at archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210524131521/https://tmh.conlangs.de/emoji-language/). Errors found, at least: _Legacy encoding windows-1252 used. Documents must use UTF-8._ and _A charset attribute on a meta element found after the first 1024 bytes._ Report the issue at https://web.archive.org/

Comment: Interesting! The Internet Archive's nginx webserver sends a HTTP `content-type` header with `text/html; charset=windows-1252` and then because of the Wayback Machine's JS/CSS includes in the HTML `head`, the original page's `meta charset` tag comes too late -- after first 1024 bytes, which violates the HTML5 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/document-metadata.html#charset

Comment: Haven't received an answer from the Internet Archive yet, but figured out a workaround based on what we discovered so far, and posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** The original page must be served with a `charset` in the HTTP `content-type` header.

---

As @JosefZ pointed out in the comments, the Wayback Machine mistakenly serves the page as `windows-1252` (which has a similar effect as `ISO-8859-1`).

This is apparently the default encoding that the Internet Archive assumes if no charset can be detected.

The `meta charset` tag in the original page's source never takes effect when the archived page is rendered by the browser, because with all the extra JavaScript and CSS included by the Wayback Machine, the tag comes *after* the first 1024 bytes, which is too late according to the HTML5 specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/document-metadata.html#charset

So it seems that the Internet Archive does not take into account `meta charset` tags when crawling a page.

However, there are other archived pages such as https://web.archive.org/web/20210501053710/https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-13.0/full-emoji-list.html where Unicode emoji are displayed correctly.

It turns out that this correctly rendered page was originally served with a HTTP `content-type` header that includes a `charset`: `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

So, if the webserver of the original page is configured to send such a `content-type` HTTP header that includes the  `UTF-8` encoding, the Wayback Machine should display the page correctly after reindexing.

How the webserver can be configured to send the encoding with the `content-type` header depends on the exact webserver that is being used.

For Apache, for example, adding

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

to the site's configuration or `.htaccess` file should work.

Note that for the Internet Archive to actually reindex the page, you may have to make a change to the original page's HTML content, not just change the HTTP headers.